# What do they mean when saying that a certain value should be “super-logarithmic”?

Tags: terminology

What do they mean when saying that a certain value should be **“super-logarithmic”**?

I've found [the Wikipedia definition of a “super-logarithm”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super-logarithm), but I'm having trouble understanding how a given value can be super-logarithmic (in some security parameter).

As for an example of the use of the terminology, see http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/yael/publications/2010-Symmetric_Encryption.pdf. It appears right in the abstract.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The term super-logarithmic in the paper you cite has nothing to do with the notion of a super-logarithm in Wikipedia. Rather, the intention is simply a function that is asymptotically larger than the $\log$ function. Formally, $f$ is super-logarithmic if $f(n)=\omega(\log n)$. The formal definition of "little-omega" appears in the Wikipedia entry on [big-O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations).

Comment: That would mean the simple $f(x)=x$ function is super-logarithmic, right?

Comment: @Yehuda how would one translate the notion of super-logarithmic to concrete terms. Meaning say you wanted concrete security with 128 bit security. What would be a plausible value of something that needed to be super-logarithmic?

Comment: @Medinoc Certainly: a linear function is super-logarithmic. Usually, we refer to this regarding the security parameter.

Comment: @giddy Typically, when you set some value $v$ to be super-logarithmic, what you are looking for is either that $2^{-v}$ be negligible or $2^v$ be out of the reach for computation. Now, when going concrete, it really depends on what exactly you mean. For example, if you are repeating a zero-knowledge proof with soundness $1/2$ until you get negligible error, then you could set $v=40$ or $v=80$ depending on what probability of error you can live with. When you need a time bound that is beyond the running time of the adversary then it is accepted to take $v=128$ today.

Comment: @YehudaLindell Just as a follow-up based on what you said -- why would the bounds be lower for negligible soundness for ZKPs? If the ZKP is part of a larger protocol (say a signing algorithm), and you want 128-bit security, wouldn't you need to set $v=128$ for the (NI)ZKP soundness as well (e.g. assuming that breaking the ZKP would allow forging)? Or is it acceptable to have lower concrete bounds for ZKP soundness?

Comment: The answer is that there is a difference between *statistical error* and *computational hardness*.

Comment: @YehudaLindell But for non-interactive ZKP's are they not the same? With enough computational power, you can brute force to find a proof that contains the statistical anomaly. (edit: the website recommends that I start a chat instead of continuing here, but sadly I do not have enough reputation to do that).

Comment: I was referring to interactive ZKP. For non-interactive, you are indeed correct.

Comment: @giddy : ​ ​ ​ Yes. ​ The point is _interaction_ vs. _local computation_ - We're more comfortable with smaller bounds on how much the adversary can _interact with honest parties_ than on how much _computation the adversary can do on its own_. ​ (You might be thinking of applying [Fiat-Shamir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiat–Shamir_heuristic) to a public-coin ZKP, but I'm not aware of anything for which the result seems at-all likely to remain a _proof_ rather than becoming just an [argument](http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~salil/research/ZKsymmetric-Mar07.pdf#page=2).) ​ ​ ​ ​